# Labels are confirmed - A passive voice or an adjective?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm rather confused regarding the following sentence:

> Labels are confirmed.

**are confirmed** represent a passive-voice or 'confirmed' is just an adjective, describing the labels?

Comment: Not much of a sentence is it? "Confirmed" is a verb.

Comment: Update - this issue has been already discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57967/i-am-surprised-passive-voice-or-adjective), it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's passive voice if adding *by X* after *confirmed* would make sense.

A speaker/writer may not add the *by X* for a few reasons:

- the speaker/writer has already said who/what X is and doesn't want to be overly repetitive
- the speaker/writer doesn't know who X is at all.

Otherwise *confirmed* would just describe the state of the labels.

In your example there isn't enough context to know 100% for sure, but heuristically it's common to want to know whether or not something is confirmed, so it's most likely being used as an adjective.

Comment: I'll give more context. Customer to supplier: "My manager has confirmed the labels, after looking into the matter." _Referring to the passive-voice option as the answer_, I guess that this active-voice should turn to a passive voice differently: **The labels have been confirmed**, but for a short Email, maybe it is too long, so the customer used shorter construction of the passive-voice, "The labels are confirmed".

Comment: In case "attached" and "confirmed" are indeed adjectives, what [type of adjective](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/english-adjectives/) are they?